# How I can make an editor in PyQt5?

Tags: pyqt5, editor

Hello I'm making a notepad in PyQt5 and I want to transform it into a code editor. I read about [that](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-codeeditor-example.html) in the QT documentation but I don't know how to make this in my code. Can you help me?

Comment: Sorry but this is not the intent of StackOverflow, as we usually answer only to specific, detailed questions, while yours is too broad. Please read [ask] and the [checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648).

Comment: Learn how to use [QScintilla](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/QScintilla/). See also [this unofficial extra documentation (for pyqt)](https://qscintilla.com/) and [the documentation for the underlying scintilla control](https://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html). This is something you will have to research yourself - nobody here is going to write the code for you or teach you how to do it.